# Does Tom Sawyer (1938) contain the n-word?

Tags: dialogue, tom-sawyer

I have fond memories of this film from my childhood and want to show it to some kids, however need to make sure it doesn't contain the n-word, which is famously used in Mark Twain's unabridged book.

IMDB's parental guide contains only the "warning" that the film portrays "bare chested boys" -- swimming in the Mississippi River or whatever, not a big deal.

An IMDB reviewer gives the hopeful sounding remark: "It should be noted that while the character of Jim is correctly depicted as a slave, the film itself is blessedly free of the racism that blights so many Hollywood films of the 1930's."

I haven't been able to find any complete transcript of spoken lines in the film online. Is there any way for me to be sure, other than to simply watch it myself before showing it to the kids?

Comment: Not according to Springfield - https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=adventures-of-tom-sawyer-the

Comment: That's exactly the kind of resource I was looking for, and will check that first next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the movie does not contain the word *nigger*.

Like Paulie_D linked in the [script](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=adventures-of-tom-sawyer-the), you can SEARCH/FIND for the word, and no matches come up. Another solution for these kinds of problems, is to search for [subtitles](https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/3332322/the-adventures-of-tom-sawyer-en) and search there, which is usually easy to do.